# How to run a .txt file which has Ruby script, without using the ruby command in the command line

Tags: ruby, argv

I'm attempting to run some ruby script in a .txt file from the command line. If I use the ruby command before I run the command, the output is what was desired, e.g.

```
ruby file_name.txt 10 40
```

How could I execute the same command without having to use the ruby command?

Comment: You _could_ set the "executable" flag on your file and add a proper shebang line on top of it, but that'd be quite weird. No one expects executable `.txt` files. (At _least_, make it an `.rb` file)

Comment: Please share the script which you want to run, I am inquisitive to see such requirement.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Yes, I've been researching on the net and I haven't quite found the solution. When you mention the "executable" flag do you mean this? `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`
Because, I've included it in the file and it doesn't make a difference when I try to execute the command.

Comment: @AshNaz87: no, that's shebang line. You set executable flag like this: `chmod +x file_name.txt`. Then you can run the file with `./file_name.txt 10 40`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a unix, you put a `#!/usr/bin/ruby` at the top of it and the `bash` shell will execute it.

If you are on Windows, I believe you must use the correct suffix, `.rb` or `.rbw`.

Comment: I'm on a Mac and using Zsh. Ruby is located in this path `/usr/local/opt/rbenv/shims/ruby` which I substituted with the one you have provided. No luck so far

Comment: it works when I use the Bash shell, but not with Zsh. If you do know the answer I'd be very much appreciative!

Comment: Ah! This is then more of a zsh question than a ruby one, as this behavior is true of shebang lines to ruby, python, etc. I don't know zsh well enough to know if what I googled up was the "right" approach or not. Sorry!

Comment: Appreciate it, regardless.

I'll also mention that you do need to change the modification so that you can execute the file. Thanks to @SergioTulentsev